# How do I auto push to subtree child repo from parents repo?

Tags: git, git-subtree

Is there any way to auto push from parents repo to child repo?

e.g)
if I revised contents in child repo's file,
right now, I am doing to push both parents and subtree child
( git push origin parents && git subtree push --prefix=child repo)

I want to know if there any way is to push both parents and child together (editing some code on child files **in parents**)

Comment: Repositories don't actually have parent/child relationships (as a formal thing anyway). When using `git subtree`, you must manually do all this kind of maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am actually using git subtree. I may not explain clearly. What I want to try is that child-subtree repo is updated automatically, if I edited child-subtree code in parents-(subtree ?) repo like a trigger.
I have already set subtree.

Comment: Git does not have "triggers", but it does have hooks. You might be able to write something using hooks. That's the *wrong way to do it though*. Don't try to do this "inside out". Instead, have whatever you do run *your command instead of `git commit`* and have your command run `git commit` and then run the various `git subtree` command(s) you'd like to run. (Replace `git commit` with `git push` if/as desired here. The point is: don't try to "trigger" it somehow, just write it.)

Comment: you meant hooks is working as like trigger?
Thank you for the details  but one thing I wonder is that the last sentence "do not try to trigger". Does it mean that you would rather not use hooks for push/commit command for git subtree?

Comment: Correct. (And: GitHub and other hosting sites *do* have things they call "triggers", which are different from Git's hooks. Because computers do what we tell them to, not what we mean, we have to be precise about which words we're using.)

Comment: Due to your advice, I figure out how to manage subtree, here is one more question about subtree. I think it might happen cuz of "inside out" reason. When I try "subtree pull" on parents, I have an error so I cannot update subtree content. The reason why I did subtree pull is that one subtree is used by other project team. So if it is edited by the team, I should update the subtree.

Comment: `git subtree` has known bugs and poor support. You may have to fix some bugs in `git subtree` yourself.

Comment: Do you think submodule is more efficient to manage projects than subtree?

Comment: It's not especially efficient or inefficient, it's just different.